# Is it possible to test IBAction?

Tags: ios, xctest, ocunit

It is kinda easy to unit test IBOutlets, but how about IBActions? I was trying to find a way how to do it, but without any luck. Is there any way to unit test connection between IBAction in a View Controller and a button in the nib file?

Comment: What you mean by "testing" ? Do you want to make unit test for those ? If so than just encapsulate your action into functions / classes and test those classes with unit tests. If you have sometehing else on your mind -please explain it a bit more.

Comment: Yes, I want to write unit test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it using OCMock, like this:

```
MyViewController *mainView =  [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[mainView view];

id mock =  [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:mainView];

//testButtonPressed IBAction should be triggered
[[mock expect] testButtonPressed:[OCMArg any]];

//simulate button press 
[mainView.testButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[mock verify];
```

If IBAction is not connected, the test will fail with error "expected method was not invoked".

Comment: I seem to be getting "expected method was not invoked", even though the IBOutlet is wired up. I even have an `NSLog` in the `viewDidLoad` which displays the correct reference to the `UIButton`.

Answer (score 10):

For full unit testing, each outlet/action needs three tests:

1. Is the outlet hooked up to a view?
2. Is the outlet connected to the action we want?
3. Invoke the action directly, as if it had been triggered by the outlet.

I do this all the time to TDD my view controllers. You can see an example [in this screencast](https://qualitycoding.org/uiviewcontroller-tdd/).

It sounds like you're asking specifically about the second step. Here's an example of a unit test verifying that a touch up inside `myButton` will invoke the action `doSomething:` Here's how I express it using [OCHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest). (`sut` is a test fixture for the system under test.)

```
- (void)testMyButtonAction {
    assertThat([sut.myButton actionsForTarget:sut
                              forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside],
               contains(@"doSomething:", nil));
}
```

Alternatively, here's a version without Hamcrest:

```
- (void)testMyButtonAction {
    NSArray *actions = [sut.myButton actionsForTarget:sut
                              forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    XCTAssertTrue([actions containsObject:@"doSomething:"]);
}
```

Comment: I am using unit testing so how to check that this button is click using like- XCTAssertTrue etc.

Comment: I am using segue on button so how can i test ?

Comment: In order to do it this way, you have to create an `IBOutlet` specifically for testing purposes. Also you have to refer to the handler in a string, which means it will break if refactored.

Comment: @jowie: AppCode automatically refactors things like that. But even without AppCode, I'm willing to pay the small price because of the ease & speed with which I can get feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I use in Swift. I created a helper function that I can use in all my UIViewController unit tests:

```
func checkActionForOutlet(outlet: UIButton?, actionName: String, event: UIControlEvents, controller: UIViewController)->Bool{
    if let unwrappedButton = outlet {
        if let actions: [String] = unwrappedButton.actionsForTarget(controller, forControlEvent: event)! as [String] {
            return(actions.contains(actionName))
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And then I just invoke it from the test like this:

```
func testScheduleActionIsConnected() {
    XCTAssertTrue(checkActionForOutlet(controller.btnScheduleOrder, actionName: "scheduleOrder", event: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside, controller: controller ))
}
```

I am basically making sure that the button btnScheduleOrder has an IBAction associated with the name scheduleOrder for the event TouchUpInside. I need to pass the controller where the button is contained as a way to verify the target for the action as well.

You can also make it a little more sophisticated by adding some other else clause in case the unwrappedButton does not exist which means the outlet is not there. As I like to separate outlets and actions tests I don't have it included here

Comment: I added a translation of this for Swift 3 below

Comment: Updated for Swift 4,  thanks to both Abbey and Julio

Answer (score 2):

Julio Bailon's answer above translated for Swift 3:

```
    func checkActionForButton(_ button: UIButton?, actionName: String, event: UIControlEvents = UIControlEvents.touchUpInside, target: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if let unwrappedButton = button, let actions = unwrappedButton.actions(forTarget: target, forControlEvent: event) {

        var testAction = actionName
        if let trimmedActionName = actionName.components(separatedBy: ":").first {
            testAction = trimmedActionName
        }

        return (!actions.filter { $0.contains(testAction) }.isEmpty)
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it is probably possible to instantiate a view controller from a storyboard or nib and then do a touch down on a UIButton. However, I wouldn't do this because you are then testing an Apple stock API. Rather, I would test by directly calling the method. For example if you have a method `- (IBAction)foo:(id)sender` in your view controller and you need to test the logic in that method, I would do something like this:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UIButton *sampleButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[sampleButton setTitle:@"Default Storyboard Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[viewController foo:sampleButton];

// Run asserts now on the logic in foo:
```

Comment: That will check the logic, but that won't check that the `UIButton` is actually wired up in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

@AbbeyJackson Swift 3 version updated to Swift 4.2, thanks to @JulioBailon for the original version.

```
 func checkActionForButton(_ button: UIButton?, actionName: String, event: UIControl.Event = UIControl.Event.touchUpInside, target: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if let unwrappedButton = button, let actions = unwrappedButton.actions(forTarget: target, forControlEvent: event) {
            var testAction = actionName
            if let trimmedActionName = actionName.components(separatedBy: ":").first {
                testAction = trimmedActionName
            }
            return (!actions.filter { $0.contains(testAction) }.isEmpty)
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Lots of good answers here already. Which works best for you depends on your testing plan.

Since this question has turned into a survey on testing methods, here's one more: if you want to test the results of manipulating your app's UI, look into the [UI Automation tool in Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW1).