# How to write unit test for button tap?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

Here I'm trying to check unit test cases for view controller.
- I have a view controller with button and label.
- When you click on the button, it will call another method. which feeds the data to the button action label text change.
- I want to check that button triggered that method or not? without adding any boolean or return type of the function.

Here is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonFetch: UIButton?

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func fetchUser() {
        self.nameLabel.text = self.getUser()
    }

    func getUser() ->String {
        return User.data()
    }
}

struct User  {
    static func data()->String{
        return "Apple"
    }
}
```

**Here is my test case**

```
func testFetchUserAction() {
        controller.buttonFetch?.sendActions(for: .touchDown)
        // I want to test the method getUser from viewcontroller gets called or not
        // some thing like this XCTAssert(self.controller.getUser(),"not called")
        XCTAssertEqual(self.controller.nameLabel.text!, "Apple")

    }
```

Comment: Why you do not use XCUITest for ui testing like button is clicked or not ?

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya Unit tests are much faster than UI tests.

Comment: Then your goals are self contradictory. Unit tests test business logic. If you want to test that tapping a button has a certain effect, that’s an UI test.

Comment: @matt Unit test test whatever you want them to. Don't limit yourself. I live on unit testing view controllers. https://qualitycoding.org/testing-view-controllers/

Comment: Worthwhile argument for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried as like below..

```
func testFetchUserAction() {

    self.controller.nameLabel.text = nil

    //Use this line, If you assigned touchUpInside to your button action
    controller.buttonFetch?.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

    //Use this line, If you assigned touchDown to your button action
    controller.buttonFetch?.sendActions(for: .touchDown)

    XCTAssert(self.controller.nameLabel.text != nil, "not called")

}
```

**Note: To make test case failed purposely, you can change UIControl.Event in sendActions**

Answer (score 4):

What you're missing:

> Make sure to call `loadViewIfNeeded()` somewhere.

This can be in the test, or in `setUp()`. This will load your outlets, and call `viewDidLoad()`.

Then, as much as possible, test the *result* of invoking an action, instead of whether or not a method was called. You've done this in your example assertion.

I'd also add that the correct action for buttons is almost always `.touchUpInside`,  not `.touchDown`. This allows the user to press a button, then drag away to change their mind. "I don't want to push this after all."

Answer (score 1):

Found something similar on another response, attempted something like this?
Source: [How to add tap action for button in "Unit Testing" and show Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321917/how-to-add-tap-action-for-button-in-unit-testing-and-show-alert)

```
func testTappingLoginButton_ShouldPresentAlert() {
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let sut = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! ViewController
    sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
    let alertVerifier = QCOMockAlertVerifier()

    sut.loginButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

    XCTAssertEqual(alertVerifier.presentedCount, 1)
}
```

Let me know if it works or not!

Answer (score 0):

*I have tried like below, its passed the test.
But I'm not sure it is correct or not?*

```
XCTAssertNotNil(self.controller!.getUser, "get user method not called")
```

Comment: Don't post updates to your question as an answer to you question. And please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Fake tap action on a button for UIViewController testing.

By using this helper, `tap(_:)`, you can verify if your button perform the
@IBAction you were expecting when testing your ViewController.

```
public func tap(_ button: UIButton) {
  button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

```swift
// Button in your UIViewController
@IBOutlet weak var primaryButton: UIButton!

// In your XCTest subclass
var sut: UIViewController!

tap(sut.primaryButton) // example of use in your test() function
```