# UI Testing in iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am pretty new to *iOS* UITesting. I'm currently writing UITest for my app using `XCTest`. I was able to test if a `UIElement` is visible or hidden when a particular button is tapped. But I wanted to test if a certain method is called when a button is tapped. How to do this? Does this come under UI testing?

I also wanted to test the `UIElement`s visible/hidden only when certain sent events are triggered instead of tap. Can we test sent events like `Touch Down` or `Touch Up Inside` of the button? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First part (testing if element is visible/hittable) is easy:

```
let button = app.buttons["yourButton"]
let element = app.cells["yourElement"]

button.tap() //tapping the button, so the element appears

if element.exists == false {
  //fail the test with custom message
}

if element.isHittable == false {
  //fail the test with custom message
}
```

You can ofc  use `XCTAsserts` for the conditions above, but the conditions above can fail with custom message. Also - if your element is not visible immediately, use `.waitForExistence` instead of `.exists`

Second part shouldn't (and cannot) be tested by UI tests - you should have unit tests for checking, if your element sends the correct logs upon interacting with it.

Yes, you could (in theory) use asserts with console output, as suggested in @Βασίλης Δ's. answer, but that is not a right way of doing UI testing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was able to test visible part of the test. I want to test if my code in `IBAction` method of a `UIButton` is being executed only when `Touch Up Inside` sent event is triggered not when `Touch Drag Outside` is triggered. Is there a way to do this. Also how can I check if a method is called when the button is tapped.

Comment: @Pradeep - its possible to test it with unit tests, as I said - check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699524/is-it-possible-to-test-ibaction

Answer (score 0):

You can technically test `Touch down` and `Touch up inside` events through UI tests, but not in a very clean way.

You can modify your element accessibility identifier by adding `_touchdown` or `_touchupinside` at the end of it, in the delegate methods. Then, in your UI test, 
 you can check if your element identifier contains the tags.